# redux-form v6 show validation error for select field

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

In v6 of redux-form we can show the errors for normal input fields like following

We can create custom renderField like this

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}/>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

And in the form, just we can use that custom renderField

```
 <Field name="username" type="text" component={renderField} label="Username"/>
```

Now  i need to know, How we can do this same for select field, and how should we pass dropdown options to this custom renderFields, Any idea to create custom renderField for select ?

Comment: this might help http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.15/examples/selectingFormValues/

Comment: it is bit outdated, am able to display the select using this, but its not tracking events, changes, values in the dropdown

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't mind some code duplication, you could do it like this:

```
const renderSelectField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error }, children }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <select {...input}>
        {children}
      </select>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Consume it in the form:

```
<Field name="username" component={renderSelectField} label="Username">
  { mySelectOptions.map(option => <option value={option.value}>{option.text}</option>) }
</Field>
```

You can see that passing the options to a select is done through `props.children`, exactly the same as when you would use the `Field` component with `component="select"`.

If you don't want the duplication, you could try to make the original `renderField` a bit smarter instead. For example, you could see if `children` contains option-tags, and if so, render the `<select>` instead of the `input`.

Comment: Amazing, Thanks for let me know about ```children``` attribute usage.

Comment: How to disable select based on local state ?

Comment: You can pass arbitrary props to the field, so just pass one for the disabled state `<Field disabled={this.state.isDisabled}>`. The 'real' `<select>` tag can now consume it.